# Which database table Liferay store default portlets configuration permissions?

Tags: configuration, liferay, portlet

I am using liferay 6.1.1 .
There is a login portlet on a page which its view permissions removed from portlet configuration so that there is no way to view the portlet and no one can login to portal!

1. Is there any way for change portlet permissions other than portlet
   configurations?
2. Which database table Liferay store default portlets
   configuration permissions?

Comment: You DO NOT want to change content in Liferay's tables manually. Seriously. In 99% of cases where somebody asks about the backend tables used to store internal information, they set themselves up for a disaster. I've seen cases where the disaster happened *months* after the manual database-write-operation. Liferay's API implementation assumes it's the only one writing to the database - do yourself a favour and don't confuse the API. (The 1% missing are people that have teammates with *a lot* of experience in Liferay implementation to double/triple check if their operation makes sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Portlet Level Permission** is used when you want to restrict the access to that Particular portlet with necessary permission then you set same through Portlet Configuration.
2. If you want the same permission for that portlet to be applicable through out the Site, Portal (i.e. login porlets in any pages of Site or Portal) you can use site role, regular role respectively from Control Panel and for **Role** >  **Define Permission** for that Particular Portlet with your desired permission that will apply to all users in that role.

For more details you can also go through Liferay Admin Guide to know more on Permissions.

Database table that store portlet permissions is **ResourcePermission**

Hope this Helps !

Comment: Yes as Olaf suggested very right, The tables are just for your reference if you change or update somethings it might mess data or create problem somewhere without knowing it is causing inconsistency.

Comment: So what should I do? A user with administrator role changes view permissions of login portlet in one of our portal instances and unfortunately the portal instance has one single page which login portlet is in it! there is no way to login to the portal instance! at last We use this (http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Managing+Instances) to remove the sub-portal.

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirement. Can you please elaborate on what is your requirement and what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Assume we have a portal instance which has one single page with one login portlet on it. A user with administrator role come and remove view permissions of login portlet so that there is no way to login to the portal instance. We search for an alternative solution to change permissions of the login portlet.

Comment: So as I understand you want to give back view permission on Login Portlet for which the Admin user had removed view permission ? If so an Portal Admin user can give back the permissions. Or re add the Login Portlet on Page. I Still could not understand why you are looking for alternate solution for it ?

Comment: Because there is only one page and only one login portlet with no view permission. there is no way to login. we can not see login portlet. we can not access to login portlet.

Comment: You can add a new login portlet again to your page is simplest solution. Because if you update permission through backend and if you are not sure that your update script is going to update right record it might cause data mismatch. But still for your reference I can tell you ResourcePermission is the table where the permission has to be updated. Make sure before you run any script backup your database. in this Table you can need find your record based on your login portlet ID, Your role Id and action ids which has numeric value for each set of permissions. You need to accordingly update Record

Comment: Layout table will have the page detail that has your login portlet.

Comment: So the only way to solve this problem is changing database manually. As Olaf said "You DO NOT want to change content in Liferay's tables manually", this is bad practice but there is no more alternative way to change permissions.

Comment: Ankit P Thank you. we solved this problem by recreating the portal instance. we remove the implicitly locked portal instance and recreate it. you can find a script to remove portal instance here (http://liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Managing+Instances)